# Opening a link in the browser in ionic/capacitor/electron platform

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I’m trying to do something very simple but yet seems impossible!

I have an `ionic-5/capacitor-3` app with iOS/Android/Electron platforms. for electron I use `@capacitor-community/electron-4` and everything so far working fine.

Recently, I needed to be able to open a link from the app in the browser, so I imported `@capacitor/browser` plugin and used `Browser.open()` which works fine in web, iOS and Android environments but does not work with electron app!

After some research, I learned that for electron app we need to import shell from electron package, and use `shell.openExternal(url)`

But the problem I’m facing is that, I have to add `electron` package and `shell` command to my main source which servers all platforms and not able to only add it to electron platform.

Another problem is that, as soon as I add electron package to main `package.json`, for some reason, ionic tries to build the main source and electron source (in `./electron` folder) same time and the fails with tons of errors because ionic is not supposed to build electron app.

Does anybody have any solution for opening a link in browser that works on all environments, including electron?

Answer (score 0):

You should open an issue in the @capacitor-community/electron-4, you would have better luck getting an answer there. Also The browser plugin seems to not support web, thus why you see it not working in electron. [Here's](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/tree/main/browser) the code that supports this. You can see there is no www folder.